# One Bitbucket/Mercurial repository using SSH. Now can't push/pull in others

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, tortoisehg

I'm using Mercurial with TortoiseHg 2.2. I have about a dozen registered repositories and I have remote repositories for most of them at Bitbucket.

I recently had to change one repository to use SSH (in order to deal with a very large file). Now I'm finding that I can't push to or pull from any of the other repositories. The error I get is:

URLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:490: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

I have Mercurial/TortoiseHg set up on another machine, where I haven't yet made the changes for that one repository. I have no trouble pushing or pulling the others there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the other repos also use SSH, or do they use HTTPS?

Comment: The others use HTTPS

Comment: And this started as of December 1, didn't it?

Comment: That's quite possible, and actually makes more sense to me than that it followed converting the one repository to use SSH. What changed December 1?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/blog/deprecating-tlsv1-tlsv1-1-2018-12-01

Comment: Thank you. I don't think I would have been able to find that on my own. Guess it means I need to update to a later version of TortoiseHg.

Comment: It was linked in a pop-up in the GUI for a month, and in a line of text on every single push for a week - not to mention the emails, tweets, Reddit/HN/Stack Overflow discussions, and other places.

Comment: Upgrading TorgtoiseHg fixed it. I'm not sure where you're saying it was mentioned. Pretty sure I would have noticed a pop-up. But the good news is my problem is solved.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53616962/getting-an-ssl-error-with-mercurial-on-bitbucket-due-to-tls