# When I hg clone i keep getting this error

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Error Message:
warning: connecting to bitbucket.org using legacy security technology (TLS 1.0); see https://mercurial-scm.org/wiki/SecureConnections for more info
abort: error: _ssl.c:510: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

My hg is version 5.3.1
I tried creating ~/.hgrc ([ui] tls = false ) but it says [ui]: command not found

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting an SSL error with Mercurial on Bitbucket due to TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53616962/getting-an-ssl-error-with-mercurial-on-bitbucket-due-to-tls)

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of HG would have this allowed. I suggest updating Ubuntu to 18.04 LTS or Xenial Xerus (depending on x64 and x86 bit architectures) or updating/downgrading HG. I believe 14.04 has lost support, so I would upgrade your OS to resolve these problems since newer versions of Ubuntu have bug fixes and upgraded support. EDIT: Ok. With the connection failure, I'd upgrade Ubuntu to get more support on what's going on.

Comment: I have 2 machines, you are correct about it will work on Ubuntu to 18.04 LTS. But I have already updated hg in the old machine and still, it does not work. I feel my python version which is 2.7 is causing the problem in the old machine (ubuntu 14.04)